# sails console with locally installed sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

According to the docs, `sails lift` will always try to run your app using the locally installed Sails module (i.e. `app/node_modules/sails`).

But when I run `sails console`, I can see from the stacktrace that it's using the globally installed instance of Sails instead:

```
at runner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/validate.js:28:16)
```

Is there a way to force `sails console` to run the locally installed version of Sails?

Answer (score 5):

If you call `sails console` from console then of course it uses a global version installed.

Open your `package.json` in your project and add a new command into `scripts` section. I offer to name it `console`.

```
"scripts": {
  "console": "sails console"
}
```

Then just call `npm run console` from your project root. This way it tries to use local version and only then global.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without global install. Just use `npx` this is the right way, react uses `create-react-app`with `npx`.

Create a new project or folder (or just go into an existing project).

```
npm init
npm install sails
npx sails console
```

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner